# Unable to create spy for NgForm object: could not find an object to spy upon for

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am having trouble creating a spy for `NgForm` object.  I am using a Angular11 component.

My test basically looks like this (abbreviated):

```
  let component: AuthComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AuthComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, 
      platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
    ....
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AuthComponent);
    ....
  }
```

And

```
describe('onSubmit', () => {
    it('makes expected calls', () => {
      const ngFormStub: NgForm = <NgForm>{};
      spyOn(ngFormStub, 'resetForm').and.callThrough();
      component.onSubmit(ngFormStub);
      expect(ngFormStub.resetForm).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

Do I need to get the value for `ngFormStub` from the fixture somehow?  I tried this and it didn't work:

```
const ngFormStub: NgForm = component.form; // this didn't work
```

But, my test shows this error:

```
Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for resetForm()
```

NOTE: On my component, the `onSubmit()` method ends with a call to `form.resetForm()`, which is what I am trying to test.

Here is my projects test config:

```
"jasmine": "^3.6.3",
"jasmine-core": "^3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^6.0.0",
"karma": "^5.2.3",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
```

Comment: did you try `const ngFormStub: NgForm = new NgForm([], []);`?  (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/11.0.2/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts#L133)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to fake out the method reference like so:

```
  ....
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const ngFormStub: NgForm = <NgForm>{
    resetForm: () => null,
    value: {
      email: "test@test.com",
      password: "password"
    },
    valid: true
  };
  ....
```

Also, I needed this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AuthComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
....
```